# Why is my python program on linux not executing after i terminate the program?

Tags: python, linux, terminal

[image: Terminal results when running a program]I am running a python script in linux and i am encountering a problem in running a program multiple times. When i execute the program ,the program runs normally and i give it a SIGTSTP signal ctrl+z to kill the program. However, when i run the program again,the program does not execute and linux prompts me to enter a new command. I tried killing pids and killing processes but its not resolve the problem. I have to restart the system in order to get the program working again. Kindly please advise for a solution so i can kill a program and run it again without having to restart my system.

Comment: Please provide some code, preferably a proof of concept.

Comment: I agree it will likely be necessary to know more about the code to understand why it doesn't exit. Otherwise, it's just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

`SIGSTOP` does not terminate the program, it pauses it, so it is not killed. you should send `SIGCONT` to the program or type `fg` to continue it.

Comment: ... and use ctrl-C instead of ctrl-Z if you want to terminate the program.

Comment: ctrl+\ seems to do the job perfectly

Answer (score 0):

SIGTSTP OR SIGSTOP signal  is suspend, can't kill this program,  use SIGCONT signal  you can wake and continue it

```
Signal  Description Signal number on Linux x86[1]
SIGABRT Process aborted 6
SIGALRM Signal raised by alarm  14
SIGBUS  Bus error: "access to undefined portion of memory object"   7
SIGCHLD Child process terminated, stopped (or continued*)   17
SIGCONT Continue if stopped 18
SIGFPE  Floating point exception: "erroneous arithmetic operation"  8
SIGHUP  Hangup  1
SIGILL  Illegal instruction 4
SIGINT  Interrupt   2
SIGKILL Kill (terminate immediately)    9
SIGPIPE Write to pipe with no one reading   13
SIGQUIT Quit and dump core  3
SIGSEGV Segmentation violation  11
SIGSTOP Stop executing temporarily  19
SIGTERM Termination (request to terminate)  15
SIGTSTP Terminal stop signal    20
SIGTTIN Background process attempting to read from tty ("in")   21
SIGTTOU Background process attempting to write to tty ("out")   22
SIGUSR1 User-defined 1  10
SIGUSR2 User-defined 2  12
SIGPOLL Pollable event  29
SIGPROF Profiling timer expired 27
SIGSYS  Bad syscall 31
SIGTRAP Trace/breakpoint trap   5
SIGURG  Urgent data available on socket 23
SIGVTALRM   Signal raised by timer counting virtual time: "virtual timer expired"   26
SIGXCPU CPU time limit exceeded 24
SIGXFSZ File size limit exceeded    25
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure your threads are running in Daemon mode.  This could be what is preventing them from exiting cleanly when you hit `ctrl-c`.  Set them up like this:

```
t = threading.Thread()
t.daemon = True  // <- this is the important bit...
t.start()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: using ctrl+\ has resolved my problem completely. It kills all processes and butchers zombies.

Answer (score -1):

Ok,I found the solution.

Enter the following command on your linux terminal:

```
ps -ef |grep yourfile.py
```

You will see a number of processes that are still running in the background. To kill them enter the following command:

```
kill -9 pid
```

Don't type pid. Type the numbers identifying the process as shown in the terminal display

[image: killing background processes that don't allow you to execute your program]

Comment: You should not use `kill -9` unless the program is not responding to regular `kill`. See also [useless use of `kill -9`](http://wwu.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#kill).

Comment: it didn't respond to any variety of kill until i entered commands in this sequence of execution

Answer (score -1):

Use the following command to kill all processes  and ensure no background processes running.

Ctrl+\